# Can not use services AngularJS - 'Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined'

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to Angularjs and everything was going well until I've got this problem.
I'm getting this error as soon as I load the page when I try to use the service inside a controller :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
at Object.instantiate (https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.5/angular.js:4145:82)
at Object.<anonymous> (https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.5/angular.js:4007:24)
>>at Object.invoke (https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.5/angular.js:4138:17)
>>at Object.enforcedReturnValue [as $get] (https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.5/angular.js:3991:37)
>>at Object.invoke (https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.5/angular.js:4138:17)
>>at https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.5/angular.js:3956:37
>>at getService (https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.5/angular.js:4097:39)
>>at Object.invoke (https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.5/angular.js:4129:13)
>>at extend.instance (https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.5/angular.js:8376:21)
>>at https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.5/angular.js:7624:13
```

This is my code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.service('Service'), function () {
    var category = { name: 'Test' };

    return {
        set: function (newObj) {
            category.name = newObj;
        },
        get: function () {
            return category;
        }
    };
};

app.controller('MainController', function (Service, $scope) {
    $scope.save = function() {
        Service.set($scope.search);
    };

    $scope.message = Service.get();
});
```

Please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not declaring your service properly. You have an addition closing `)` in service declaration.

Line:

```
app.service('Service'), function () {
```

Should Be:

```
app.service('Service', function () {
```

Comment: Thank you! You get blind when you look at some code for more then 5h :)

Answer (score 3):

In case you're using `TypeScript` you have to make sure the `class definition` is above the `angular.module` defintion.

Wrong:

```
angular.module('app').service('Service', Service);

class Service {

}
```

Correct:

```
class Service {

}

angular.module('app').service('Service', Service);
```